# Unable to resolve ${...} in @PropertySource when using Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring's Java configuration to configure my application. Below is a snippet of the annotations. There is no problem with the application deployed to the Tomcat container. The `${CONFIG_PATH}` resolves correctly as the `CONFIG_PATH` is defined in the system/environment properties.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = { Configuration.class }) })
@PropertySource(value = { "file:${CONFIG_PATH}/app.properties" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class AppConfig { ... }
```

I recently started using Spring-Boot so that I can build a standalone executable jar with Tomcat embedded. However, now the `@PropertySource(value = { "file:${CONFIG_PATH}/app.properties" })` does not work; it results in the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found: file:${CONFIG_PATH}/app.properties
```

My temporary solution is to hardcode the path as follows.

```
//@PropertySource(value = { "file:${CONFIG_PATH}/app.properties" })
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/usr/local/etc/app.properties" })
```

I'm still relatively new to the Spring camp. So I'm sure that I'm missing something. I greatly appreciate any help on this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**:
I looked the at the default `appplication.properties` and found the 4 location given to be wanting. For reasons of clean deployment, properties file should be not located in the classpath. And having the properties file located relative to where the application is located makes it harder to manage the configuration if we have more than one application deployed.

Comment: Why do you need an additional properties file? Why not simply use the default `application.properties`?

Comment: I had experimented with that, but the 4 locations are not what we want to look for the file. And I'm unaware on how to specify a different location to look for the `application.properties` file.

Comment: I just added the feature you need (i.e. placeholder resolution in `@PropertySource` by the `ConfigFileApplicationListener`). It happens super early in the context lifecycle so the only property sources available for resolution will be system properties, env vars and the command line. The answer below also is valid as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spring Boot [README](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html)

> If you don't like application.properties as the configuration file name you can switch to another by specifying spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location using the spring.config.location environment property.

I would probably just use this startup parameter (in a bootscript or something) to specify the configuration file.

I guess the reason the replacement doesn't work is due to the nature of spring boot. The application context is also used to bootstrap/configure the servlet container and as such the normal rules for `@PropertySource` probably doesn't apply. You could (or maybe should) [register an issue](http://jira.springsource.org) for this.

Comment: Perhaps the only viable solution so far. I guess doing `java -jar project.jar --spring.config.location=/usr/local/etc/application.properties` is just as good as using an environment variable.

Comment: An environment variable would work as well if you prefer that (`SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION`).